# How do you set the --frames option for a Javadoc task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, javadoc, frames

We recently updated to JDK 11 and the javadoc team has seen fit to remove frame generation from the javadocs in favor of a search box.  Our community is comprised heavily of students who don't know what keywords to search for, but who can browse a sidebar and find what they need.  For them a search box is useless.  They require discovery through browsing.  For that reason, we would like to turn frames back on by adding the --frames option to the javadoc task, and then we'll just never move off of JDK 11.

We are using Gradle 7.4.2 and there doesn't appear to be a method exposing the --frames option in the [StandardJavadocDocletOptions](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/StandardJavadocDocletOptions.html) class.

If the options section of my Javadoc task looks like this:

```
   options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PROTECTED
   options.links "https://developer.android.com/references"
   options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

Then I see those options in gradle's generated options file.

Adding...

```
   options.setStringOption('-frames')
```

...does not result in any new option appearing in the generated options file.  To be honest I have no idea what setStringOption() without the second string parameter actually does.

Adding...

```
   options.setStringOption('-frames', '')
```

... results in --frames '' appearing on the generated options file, but that confuses javadoc.

I don't see anything in the Gradle documentation that indicates how one might add simply '--frames' to the command line of the javadoc executable.  Or any other option that javadoc might expose, but the gradle version one is sitting on does not expose for that matter.

Comment: Can you try `addBooleanOption('frames', true)`? https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-send-x-option-to-javadoc/23384/9

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you @aSemy.  I'd mark this as the answer were it not a comment on my question.  The comment in the referenced thread where Vampire explains that an option with no value is simply a boolean option seems obvious in retrospect, but the documentation [Gradle documentation for addBooleanOption](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/CoreJavadocOptions.html#addBooleanOption-java.lang.String-) would benefit from the same clarifying text.

Answer (score 0):

To set flags use [`addBooleanOption()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/external/javadoc/CoreJavadocOptions.html#addBooleanOption-java.lang.String-boolean-)

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

tasks.javadoc {
    options {
        require(this is StandardJavadocDocletOptions) // workaround https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7038
        addBooleanOption("frames", true)
    }
}
```

Note that the Kotlin DSL requires a workaround https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7038#issuecomment-448294937